# Using the If function to extract data from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

By using the sample dataset found in [Using "If" function to extract data from another worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60657909/using-if-function-to-extract-data-from-another-worksheet), I am trying to use the VBA's If function to look for a specific keyword, and if there's a match, I would want to extract the Name itself, alongside its Serial Number and Product, and add to the last row of another worksheet, within the same workbook.
 
For instance, If in column C, we detect, say, cana (note that this is not an exact match, but good enough), then I would want VBA to help me to extract Canary Wharf, its Serial Number and Product next to it, which are 8273615 and Canned Food, to the end of another worksheet, and the loop goes on until the end of Canary Wharf and moves on to Riverdale, which I would type, say, riverd, and repeat the same process. The x's are there to signify that I have a rather large dataset, nothing else.

I have used the code below to carry out the task:

```
Option Compare Text
 
Sub DataExtraction()
 
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range, i As Integer
 
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
 
 
Set SrchRng = ws1.Range("A1:A100")
 
For Each cel In SrchRng
    For i = 1 To 10
        For k = 1 To 1
        If InStr(1, cel(i, k).Value, "cana") > 0 Then
            ActiveCell(i, k).Value = "Canary Wharf"
            ActiveCell(i, k + 1).Value = cel(i, k + 1).Value
            ActiveCell(i, k + 2).Value = cel(i, k + 2).Value
        End If
        Next k
    Next i
Next cel
 
End Sub
```

The code above imported 10 same inputs, namely, Canary Wharf, 8273615, Canned Food, for 10 times, I suspect it was because of my `For i = 1 To 10`  command. My desired end goal, is to let VBA extract Canary Wharf until there are no Canary Wharf's left, alongside the two inputs to its right. In other words, it would be a 2x3 Matrix that I am looking at. Then, naturally, I would move to Riverdale, and the cycle goes on.

Comment: `If InStr(1, cel.Value, "cana") > 0 Then`

Comment: What is the purpose of the `i` loop here?

Comment: yes the i and the k loop seem not necessary. Try to delete them completely. Instead check out some code for detection of the last cell of the target-worksheet, so the new entries are not written over the last ones but into the first empty row.